# Is there a difference in decrement operatos in D?

Tags: d

I'm using a dynamic array to implement my stack. I wrote pop as the following:

```
int pop() {
        int n = arr[--arr.length];
        return n;
}
```

Using above code I get an `Range violation` error at run-time. But using the following code:

```
int pop() {
        int n = arr[arr.length - 1];
        arr.length--;
        return n;
}
```

It works fine. I don't understand why, to me both should be equivalent. What am I missing?

EDIT:
maybe is this why `--arr.length` cause element I'm going to access be "removed" from array?

Also, `push(N)` is just `arr ~= n;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're removing the element before you grab it. You have to retrieve the element, and then reduce the size of the array.

`--arr.length` is reducing the length of the array, and then returning the new reduced size. You then attempt to do `int n = arr[arr.length]`.

Here's a simple work-through of `int n = arr[ --arr.length ]` with one element:

- arr.length = 1
- last element is at position 0
- evaluate `--arr.length`

  - arr is reduced to zero elements
  - arr.length returns 0
- evaluate `int n = arr[0]`.

  - arr is empty, breaks.